# update a field in a table showing error

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

I've a customer table i that table in one i need to store data of customer as a text a declare that in db that varchar(1500) while am trying to update that field i getting following erro

You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galle' at line 1"

```
field name is "comments1 varchar(1500);"
```

My query is

```
$sql="UPDATE customer SET comments1='".$comments1."' WHERE sno='$sno'";
```

how to solve it...

Comment: $sql="UPDATE `customer` SET  `comments1`='".$comments1."' WHERE sno='$sno'";

Answer (score 4, accepted):

before your query add this code

```
$comments1=mysql_real_escape_string($comments1);
```

<----your query goes here--->

Answer (score 1):

According to the error message:

> ...or the right syntax to use near **'s standard dummy text ever since**
>   
>                                       error starts here ^

Probably you are inserting a value that has single quote (*which breaks the sql statement causing syntax error*) on it. This is an indicator that you have not sanitized the values before inserting it on the database. There are several ways to avoid from sql injection:

- by using `PDO`
- and the other one: `MySQLi`.

For more details, please browse on this link.

- [How to *prevent SQL injection* in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-to-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)

---

you can also use [**mysql_real_escape_string**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php) (*but will soon be deprecated*)

```
$var = mysql_real_escape_string($comments1);
$sql="UPDATE customer SET comments1='$var' WHERE sno='$sno'";
```

Answer (score 1):

Your comment variable contains single quotes you need to escape them with addslashes function.

Try this

```
$sql="UPDATE customer SET comments1='".addslashes($comments1)."' WHERE sno='$sno'";
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems your column name is `comments` not `comments1`. `field name is "comments varchar(1500);"` so change

```
$sql="UPDATE customer SET comments1='".$comments1."' WHERE sno='$sno'";
```

to

```
 $sql="UPDATE customer SET comments='".$comments1."' WHERE sno='$sno'";
```

Answer (score 0):

Better try to use this function   mysql_real_escape_string()